# File download in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, download

I have a link on my website.Whenever user clicks on this link a pdf file is downloaded on this action.
But there is a problem if a user know the file link he/she directly add address of file in browser and can download file as well.
What i want to protect it being downloaded directly by entering file url in browser address bar.
Any suggestion for this is well come.

Regards

SYED

Answer (score 0):

Well,

- you can use a token (this 'token' is saved in a input type='hidden' name='token' value='token value' of HTML Element,to use later)
- check if the referer is of your form page

the 'token',you check on hour of start downloading of pdf file.

I don't can make this in asp.net,but you can take look to ASP.net.

simple example code:

```
<?
$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid()); 
echo "<form method='POST' action=""><input type='hidden' name='token' value='$token'>
      <input type='submit' value='Go!'>"; 

if($_POST["token"] == $token) {
    //show link pdf file
}else {
   die('Access denied');
}

?>
```

I don't says what this is total security,says is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in one of the website folder and set the authentication to this folder from web.config using form authentication and location attribute. Users need to login in order to download PDF.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/adminlogin.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30"></forms>
        </authentication>

        <location path="[PDF Folder]">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="[role]"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

This is only sample Get more details about above from net.
```